# How to fix jquery ui tabs widget's height?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I hooked up that jquery tabs widget to my website. It works fine, the only problem is that the last tab jumps down on zoom in. How do I fix the hight of the widget so it remains stationary on zoom in/zoom out?

Comment: "Jumps down"? Does that mean the text wraps or the tabs wrap?

Comment: I think it means tabs wrap... Imagine all tabs were at one level on 100% zoom, and on 115% zoom the last tab all of a sudden is below the first one.